# Weird iphone 6 plus screen size on simulator (vs launch screen image)

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, iphone-6-plus

If i run eg iPhone 6 simulator and save a screenshot, the dimensions are 750x1334 (which is expected eg for launch screen image), but if i run iPhone 6 plus simulator and save the screenshot i get image with dimensions 1242x2208.

What's going on? The expected screen size for iPhone6 plus is 1080x1920px. In other words all other devices in simulator do create images with expected size except iPhone 6 plus.

Why? How to get proper image size from simulator?

I have to probably resize the image (at least it is bigger than required - 115% of expected size) but still quite unexpected.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that if i tried to use 1080x1920px dimensions as launch image for iPhone6 plus, it doesn't work (at least in simulator)

And that's the official dimensions mentioned [eg here](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/graphics/launch-screen/).

But, if i supply the dimension i get from simulator (1242x2208) the launch image for iPhone 6 does work. So the simulator dimensions are correct. It seems.